# Getting 'Invalid use of property' when using Property Set in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, properties

I know there are tons of threads and questions about this and it's pretty obvious, generally, where the error is. Most folks aren't using the SET keyword when moving objects around. I am.

Here's what's happening:

This is in an excel sheet so I've made a little set of functions to keep track of the columns and make an index so that each time the app runs it will reindex the columns so I can do things like `.Cells(row_num, pCust_index("custID"))` in case of column changes.

I have a form called custContagions. It's just a little modal window that allows users to add/remove/edit customer's contagious status. It contains a property:

```
Private pCust_index as dictionary
```

It also contains this property setter:

```
Public Property Set set_cust_index(ByRef custIndex As Dictionary)
    Set pCust_index = New Dictionary
    Set pcust_index = custIndex
End Property
```

Pretty straight forward right? Takes a dictionary object, resets my index and points to the existing passed object.

Now, on the calling form I have the other side:

```
Private Sub newCustContagious_LBL_Click()
    Dim contForm as New custContagions
        Call contForm.set_cust_index(pCust_index)  'note pCust_index is a private here too
        Call contForm.Show
...
```

I'm getting the Invalid Use of Property compiler error on the set_cust_index call.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most folks aren't using the SET keyword when moving objects around

Then they are not moving objects around. The `Set` keyword is the way to move object around.
There is also `CopyMemory` to directly copy the `ObjPtr`, but I do not believe most folks do that.

> Pretty straight forward right?

Not quite. You create a dictionary, immediately discard it and replace with another dictionary passed as a parameter. You should remove the first of the two lines, and make the param `ByVal`:

```
Public Property Set set_cust_index(ByVal custIndex As Dictionary)
    Set pcust_index = custIndex
End Property
```

> I'm getting the Invalid Use of Property compiler error

You declared a property and then use it as a sub. With a property, you should have done:

```
Set contForm.set_cust_index = pCust_index
```

At which point the `set_cust_index` name does not look great. It would make a sensible name for a sub (`Public Sub set_cust_index(ByVal custIndex As Dictionary)`), but for a property you would be better off with `Public Property Set cust_index(ByVal custIndex As Dictionary)`.

Comment: @ the dictionary discarding, that is intentional to clear the existing one, tho I suppose setting to NULL or NOTHING would have been a better choice.

I see what is happening now I think.  I'm used to PHP wherein I make a function who's job it is to be a set/get rather than a separate flavor of sub.  WIll try this now.

Comment: @meteorainer The fact you assign an object variable to something else already clears the reference to the previous object. If there is no more references to that object, it will be destroyed. If there are other references to that object, it will not be destroyed regardless of whether or not you set the variable to something else.

Comment: Worked like a charm. +1 to you.  Marking as a resolution to my lack of proper class management.  Thanks!

Comment: You are not "clearing" anything, you are merely swapping references stored in a variable, and you do it twice where one time would suffice. If you did something like `pCust_index.Clear()`, that would be different and would make sense, but then you'd also have something like `pCust_index.LoadNewData(custIndex)` instead of creating a new object. *(Posted as a new comment because too long; intended to be continuation of the previous comment).*

Comment: I've got it cleaned up now. I'm still fairly new and am completely unfamiliar with garbage collection in vb.

Comment: @meteorainer VB6/VBA (as opposed to VB.NET) do not use garbage collection. Object destruction is deterministic and is managed with [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) (also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687260.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4947zb56.aspx)). VB hides the manual bits and automatically calls `AddRef` upon assigning an object to a variable and `Release` upon overwriting the stored reference with something else.